# C# Initialize abstract class like Java

Tags: java, c#

In Java I'm able to have a class like this:

```
public abstract class Button{
    public abstract void onClick();
}
```

Then initialize it by using:

```
Button b = new Button(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(){
    // Things
    }
}
```

Now is there any way to do a similar thing in C#?

Or would my best bet be to use an event?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question about C# syntax.  But I don't think we can answer a question about an event.  The reason for having an abstract class with an `onClick` method would be because there are platforms such as Swing or the Android runtime that expect to use classes that have `onClick` defined.  Are you using some platform like that in C#?  Or are you writing your own platform?

Comment: C# doesn't have the equivalent of anonymous classes. But you can use delegates and lambdas for similar effect.

Comment: I am using my own platform, so I don't need it to be a onClick method. It's just that in Java I would use something like what I posted above, as where in C# I'm not to sure what would be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone else trying to do something similar. @shmosel suggested lambdas, and so that is what I used.

```
public class Button(){
    private Action _onClick;

    public Button(Action onClick){
        _onClick = onClick;
    }

    //Other method that calls _onClick()
}

//Other Class
Button b = new Button(() => {/*Do Code Here*/});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Abstract Class you need to have another class inherited from that Abstract Class and use it to initialize abstract class like this:

```
    public class MeSecondClass : MyClass
    {
        public override void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public abstract class MyClass
    {
        public abstract void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args);
    }


    MyClass  a = new MeSecondClass();
```

Comment: This is a better approach than using delegates since it can handle the general case where more than one method may be involved.

Answer (score 1):

The comparable approach in C# to Java's anonymous inner classes feature is to instantiate a dynamic object and convert it to the abstract class. Unfortunately you have to implement the conversion yourself.
Example:

```
using System;

namespace AnonymousInnerClassExample
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Button button = Button.CreateFromDynamic(new
            {
                OnClick = new Action(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hit OnClick");
                })
            });
            button.OnClick();
        }

        public abstract class Button
        {
            public abstract void OnClick();
            public static Button CreateFromDynamic(dynamic button)
            {
                return new Implementation(button);
            }
            private class Implementation : Button
            {
                public Implementation(dynamic button)
                {
                    PrivateOnClick = button.OnClick;
                }
                private Action PrivateOnClick { get; set; }

                public override void OnClick()
                {
                    PrivateOnClick();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers show, you CAN do something similar, but really the question is 'Should you?' and the answer is no.

Events were created for just this sort of thing, so use an event. Not only is it clearer and cleaner code, but it is a well established pattern that C# devs will know, so using it help with maintainability of your code.